# TinyMCE - Not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation     path>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
    "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft     aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link     image",
toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
image_advtab: true,
templates: [
    {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
    {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
]
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
</form>
```

I copied this code to my html file from this web address http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php 
so when I copied it over to my html file and open it in a browser I get this:

[image]

it's just blank like a regular textarea not like what it shows at http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

any help

Thank You

Comment: Your source is wrong src="<your installation     path>

Comment: okay i see i need to fix it add it as a answer i will except it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your source is wrong `src="<your installation path>"` change this to your installation path.

STEPS TO INSTALL TINYMCE:

**Step 1: Download a copy of TinyMCE and put it on a web server.**

Download a copy of the TinyMCE package from TinyMCE Downloads.
Unzip the package and move the `"tinymce/js/tinymce"` directory into a web accessible location on your web server (for example, localhost).
**Step 2: Add TinyMCE to a page.**

With TinyMCE accessible via your web server (http://localhost/tinymce/), you can now include the TinyMCE script anywhere you would like to use the TinyMCE editor.

To add the script, add the following inside your page's  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

**Step 3: Initialize TinyMCE as Part of a Web Form**

With the script included, you may then initialize TinyMCE on any element (or elements) in your webpage.

TinyMCE lets you identify elements to replace via a CSS3 selector.  To add TinyMCE to a page you pass an object that contains a selector to tinymce.init().

In this example, you will replace  with a TinyMCE editor by passing the selector '#mytextarea' to tinymce.init().

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#mytextarea"
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TinyMCE Getting Started Guide</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Installation

Comment: did you download tinymce.min.js? you have to add this in your js to use it. take a look at this working example it might also help you http://jsfiddle.net/TgZXL/75/

Comment: i added steps to install tinymce in your page.